# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_25 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

Tags: python, keras, image-recognition

I'm trying to train a model for multi label  image recognition (with four classes).

The code for building the model is as following

```
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150, 150, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(
  optimizer='sgd',
  loss='mse',
  metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000 // batch_size,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800 // batch_size)
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3441, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-14-184aec507731>", line 6, in <module>
    validation_steps=800 // batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1732, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_generator.py", line 220, in fit_generator
    reset_metrics=False)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1508, in train_on_batch
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 621, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "C:\Users\user\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_25 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

Do I have to reshape the data?

I need help in solving this please.

Comment: If you have four classes your last Dense layer needs to output 4 units. You should use `softmax` activation function as well.

Comment: Did that help @Morgenstern?

Comment: @Jakob Yes, thank you. But I ended up rewriting the entire neural network, I had a low performance on my original model due to insufficient amount of relu layers and too many pixels in the training img


Edit: sorry for the late reply